# Bash: Eval & Tee: how to have Output, Captured Output and Error Check

Tags: bash, shell-script, tee

using `#!/bin/bash` under Ubuntu 16.04 I want to an eval'ed command to...

- deliver direct output
- get the output to a variable
- check on the result of the eval

```bsh
# valid command
foo=$(eval "ls" | tee /dev/tty);
echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
echo $foo

# invalid command
foo=$(eval "ls -ßnonsense" | tee /dev/tty);
echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
echo $foo
```

My problem is, that I only get a meaningful `PIPESTATUS`, when

- I completely take out the `tee /dev/tty` (otherwise, yes, it covers up any eval-failure as part of the first pipe command)
- or put it outside the bracket `foo=$(eval "ls" ) | tee /dev/tty;` – ...but in that case, I no longer get neither direct output nor $foo output.

Comment: Why the use of `eval`? when you can run just `ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zsh` instead:

```
shell_code='ls' # or ls -ßnonsense...
{ foo=$(eval " $shell_code" >&1 >&3 3>&-); } 3>&1
print -r status=$? output=$foo
```

Here, we're duplicating the original stdout (which would only be the controlling tty if that script was run unredirected from a terminal) onto fd 3, and redirect `eval`'s output to both the command substitution and that fd 3 (using zsh's own `tee`ing mechanism when a fd is redirected more than once for output).

With `bash` and other shells supporting `pipefail` (though not ksh93 if on Linux/Cygwin) on systems with `/dev/fd/<n>`, you can do something similar with:

```
shell_code='ls' # or ls -ßnonsense...
{
  foo=$(
    set -o pipefail
    eval " $shell_code" 3>&- | 
      tee 4>&1 >&3 3>&- /dev/fd/4
  )
} 3>&1

printf 'status=%s output=%s\n' "$?" "$foo"
```

With `pipefail` on, the exit status of a pipeline is that of the rightmost command in the pipeline that failed. So here it will be that of `eval` unless `tee` fails.

To get the exit status of `eval` unconditionaly, with `bash`, you can do:

```
shell_code='ls' # or ls -ßnonsense...
{
  foo=$(
    eval " $shell_code" 3>&- |
      tee 4>&1 >&3 3>&- /dev/fd/4
    exit "$PIPESTATUS"
  )
} 3>&1

printf 'status=%s output=%s\n' "$?" "$foo"
```

In those approaches, `tee`'s stdout is the original stdout, while the command substitution pipe is fed by way of `/dev/fd/4`. We're doing that rather than the other way round (`tee`'s stdout to command substitution pipe, writing to original stdout via some `/dev/fd/<n>`) even though that makes the code a bit more complicated,  to work around the fact that the latter wouldn't work on Linux or Cygwin systems, where opening `/dev/fd/<n>` is not the same as duplicating fd `<n>` (but doing it for a fd that points to the writing end of a pipe, like for that command substitution (not ksh93 that uses socketpairs instead) is functionally equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portable solution that should work with most if not all Bourne syntax shell; tested with `bash`, `dash`, `ksh93`, `ksh88`, `ash`, (Bourne) `sh` and `zsh`:

```
for command in "ls -ßnonsense" "ls -ld /tmp"; do
    foo=`{ eval "$command"; echo $? > /tmp/ps.$$; } | tee /dev/tty;`
    st=`cat /tmp/ps.$$;rm /tmp/ps.$$`
    echo "foo=$foo status=$st"
done
```

Comment: I need eval because the script bit actually come in a variable (I write some kind of execute-and-assert-function)). I need the pipestatus in a variable, non on screen. And $foo needs to get the eval'ed commands stdout), which would not "pipe through" your echo pipestatus“. (I assume you  mean to have a closing `)` at the very end?)

Comment: There was a typo. Answer modified to avoid bashisms or whatever dependence on specific shells features.